# How can I retrieve the current URL in Next.js 13 with server-side rendering and support for static exports?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm aiming to hide specific elements or content on a particular URL in a Next.js 13. However, using client-side methods like `usePathname()` or other hooks is not an option because my page is generated on the server. Additionally, using `headers()` for conditional rendering is unsupported when exporting the site as static files. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?